# Disadvantages due to many long running (program execution time) background tasks in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Situation Description:

A `BackgroundService` is registered in a `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Host`. Depending on the configuration, this background service builds subscriptions to, for example, an MQTT broker and makes the data available. For each subscription, a new instance of a class is created, which is started by a method call.

Inspired by the class `BackgroundService` in `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting` the idea is to start the subscriptions via a method `Task RunAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)`. The task the method returns would run until the `stoppingToken` is canceled. Since, depending on the configuration, this leads to hundreds of calls to this method. This makes me wonder if this can lead to problems, since so many tasks are created that are not finished over the entire runtime of the program. The advantage over two methods, `Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)` and `StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)` I see in the fact that I can handle logging and exceptions quite normally in try catch.

In summary, it makes sense to have many tasks that exist over almost the entire runtime of the application?

Example:

```
public interface IBackgroundServieTask
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Run a task that stars the task and clean up after the stopping token is called.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="stopptingToken">A token to stop the run.</param>
    Task Run(CancellationToken stopptingToken);
}
```

The tasks would not do much. After all, that shouldn't lead to any resource usage? Or does this put a heavy load on task management.  This is what most tasks would look like.

```
public async Task Run(CancellationToken stopptingToken)
{
    // (async) start actions
    await Task.Delay(-1, stopptingToken);
    // (async) stop actions
}
```

Further, I plan to work with Observalbes. Which can probably be similar to timers. Here is an example, but the Observalbe could also be the MQTT subscription:

```
public async Task Run(CancellationToken stopptingToken)
{
    // (async) start actions
    // example observable to do something
    await Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
        .Do(t => DoSomething(t))
        .IgnoreElements()
        .TakeUntil(Observable.Create<Unit>(o =>
        {
            return stopptingToken.Register(() =>
            {
                o.OnCompleted();
            });
        }))
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
        .ToTask();
    // (async) stop actions
}
```

Here is the advantage, I can still execute a stop asynchronously after the Observable and can use the ILogger context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few possible problems with many background tasks

#### Threadpool exhaustion

background tasks are normally run on the threadpool. This has only so many threads. There is a mechanism for adding and removing threads, but this is purposely designed to be slow. When creating tasks you can specify [`TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions?view=net-6.0), this hints the pool that additional threads may be needed.

### Resource usage

Tasks are run on threads, and threads need some resources to run, notably some stack memory. However, your probably does not do actual work most of the time, so if they use `await` while waiting for something to happen, no thread is used, and any resources can be used for something else.

### Timers

If most background tasks are for performing periodic tasks, then timers may be a better alternative.

### Scheduling

If background tasks need to keep most resources free for the foreground work, then you might consider using a [LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler?view=net-6.0)  to ensure the background tasks only uses up a fixed number of threads.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
The tasks would not do much. Please see the addition to the post.

Comment: @mmuecke both examples uses await, so would not use much resources while awaiting, just an object for the state machine. If you await a `Task.Delay` in a loop you just have a complicated wrapper around a timer, so might just use the timer directly. If you want to run the "stop" code when the cancellationToken is canceled, you could just register a callbak on the token, but either variant is fine really.